# Best way of implementing a circular buffer

Tags: c++, beginner, queue, circular-list

I wanted to implement a circular buffer for learning purpose only.

My first option was to use a secondary status for rear and front pointers: (Like the ones I've seen in many websites)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class ql
{
    public:
        ql(int size)
        {
            this->size = size;
            data = new T[size];
            front = NULL;
            rear = NULL;
        }

        ~ql()
        {
            delete[] data;
        }

        void enQueue(T item)
        {
            T *nf = nextPtr(rear);

            if (nf != front)
            {
                if (front == NULL)
                    front = &data[0];

                *nf = item;
                rear = nf;
                cout << item << " Added. ^_^" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "OverFLO@#R$MR... X_X" << endl;
        }

        T *deQueue()
        {
            if (rear != NULL)
            {
                T *p = front;
                if (front == rear)
                {
                    front = NULL;
                    rear = NULL;
                } 
                else
                    front = nextPtr(front);
                cout << *p << " is going to be returned. -_-" << endl;
                return p;
            }
            else
                cout << "Empty... >_<" << endl;
        }
    private:
        T *nextPtr(T *p)
        {
            if (p == &data[size - 1] || p == NULL)
                return &data[0];
            return p + 1;
        }

        T *data, *rear, *front;
        int size;
};

int main()
{
    ql<int> q(3);

    q.enQueue(1);
    q.enQueue(2);
    q.enQueue(3);
    q.enQueue(4);

    cout << endl;
    q.deQueue();
    q.deQueue();
    q.deQueue();
    q.deQueue();

    cout << endl;
    q.enQueue(5);
    q.enQueue(6);

    cout << endl;
    q.deQueue();
    q.deQueue();
    q.deQueue();

    return 0;
}
```

My second option was to sacrifice a space for the sake of distinguishing between empty and full circular buffers: (I saw this one on Ellis's Fundamentals of data structures)

```
template<class T>
class ql
{
    public:
        ql(int size)
        {
            this->size = size;
            data = new T[size];
            front = 1;
            rear = 0;
        }

        ~ql()
        {
            delete[] data;
        }

        void enQueue(T item)
        {
            if ((rear + 2) % size != front)
            {
                rear = (rear + 1) % size;
                data[rear] = item;
                cout << item << " Added. ^_^" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "OverFLO@#R$MR... X_X" << endl;
        }

        T *deQueue()
        {
            if ((rear + 1) % size != front)
            {
                T *p = &data[front];
                cout << *p << " is going to be returned. -_-" << endl;
                front = (front + 1) % size;
                return p;
            }
            else
                cout << "Empty... >_<" << endl;
        }
    private:
        T *data;
        int size, rear, front;
};
```

and my last option was to use another variable for storing used space in circular buffer:

```
template<class T>
class ql
{
    public:
        ql(int size)
        {
            this->size = size;
            data = new T[size];
            buffer = 0;
            front = 1;
            rear = 0;
        }

        ~ql()
        {
            delete[] data;
        }

        void enQueue(T item)
        {
            if (buffer != size)
            {
                buffer++;
                rear = (rear + 1) % size;
                data[rear] = item;
                cout << item << " Added. ^_^" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "OverFLO@#R$MR... X_X" << endl;
        }

        T *deQueue()
        {
            if (buffer != 0)
            {
                buffer--;
                T *p = &data[front];
                cout << *p << " is going to be returned. -_-" << endl;
                front = (front + 1) % size;
                return p;
            }
            else
                cout << "Empty... >_<" << endl;
        }
    private:
        T *data;
        int size, buffer, rear, front;
};
```

Which one of this approaches do you think is the best?
I'm also looking for advises on how to change this class for practical using.
thanks

Comment: If you're a language beginner you might want to add [tag:beginner] to the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use better names and do not use `using namespace` in headers

The name `q1` is rather arbitrary. `queue` or `circular_queue` is a lot better. That, by the way, is a perfect example why you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` when you write a header. There's already `std::queue`, so a `queue` would conflict with `std::queue`.

Since you're writing a *template class* all your code will reside in a header at some point, [so `using namespace` is out of the question either way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)

## Use a smarter data store

Use [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::deque<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead of raw pointers for the memory. Or re-use [`std::queue<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), unless you want to practice writing a `queue` completely by hand.

## Use `return` instead of `cout`

Instead of `cout << … <<` return `bool` or a custom enum in `enQueue`. If I want to store elements in a circular buffer, I need to know whether `enQueue` worked. I cannot check stdout for error messages.

## Sizes are positive

Use `size_t` for sizes, not `int`.

## Check all return paths

Return `nullptr` (C++11 or higher) or `0` in `deQueue` if the queue is empty. However, a pointer at that point is dangerous: the user *must* make a copy at some point, or they might end up with another object. Use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) if you have C++17 at hand instead, or

```
 bool deQueue(T & dest) {
     if(…) {
         // queue has elements
         dest = …;
         …
         return true;
     } else {
         // queue has no elements
         return false;
     }
 }
```

`enQueue` could use a `const T&` instead of a `T`, by the way. Or you could use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) for movable types.

## All at once

If you follow these guidelines, you will end up

```
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
class queue
{
    public:
        explicit queue(size_t size) : m_size(size) { }

        queue(const queue<T> & other) = default;
        queue(queue<T> && other) = default;
        queue& operator=(const queue<T> & other) = default;
        queue& operator=(queue<T> && other) = default;

        bool enQueue(T item)
        {
            if(m_data.size() == m_size) {
                return false;
            } else {
                m_data.push(std::move(item));
                return true;
            }
        }

        std::optional<T> deQueue()
        {
            if(m_data.empty()) {
                return std::nullopt;
            } else {
                std::optional<T> result = m_data.front();
                m_data.pop();
                return result;
            }
        }

        size_t capacity() const
        {
            return m_size;
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            return m_data.size();
        }
    private:
        size_t m_size;
        std::queue<T> m_data;
};
```

If you don't want to re-use `std::queue` or `std::deque`, I'd go with `std::vector` and your third approach.

Congratulations on your first approach, by the way. I've seen raw-pointer usage going wrong too many times, and it's refreshing to see some clever use there. Well done. But that's more or less the way you would do it in C (sans template and `class`, of course).

But you will probably admit that working with pointers at that point is somewhat a headache. Both `front` and `rear` (as pointers) can be expressed as `data + x` and `data + y` for two suitable `int` `x` and `y`, like  you did in your second approach.

Either way, unless you *really* need to use raw pointers use either smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`) or (better) full containers like `std::vector`.